# Managing different organizations on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently, we have our own Azure active directory and azure subscription for our organization. Now I want to On-Board different organizations and users in different organizations into our Azure. infrastructure. I want to manage resources for all the organizations and want to get billing details of each organization.
There are two ways to On-Board different organizations

**Create separate AAD and Subscription for each organization** - Clear separation between organizations makes it easier to get billing details for each resource group. But this option could not be cost-effective as we need to create the same resource for each organization

**Create an AAD group for each organization in our Azure active directory and use our main subscription for all organizations** - We need to add resource tagging to each Azure resource to get the usage details and billing for each organization. This could be cost-effective but will not get the all the features of azure cost management like alerts, budget, etc.

Please let me know which option should be used in this scenario while On-Boarding a large number of organizations and users?
Let me know other Pros and Cons of each option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to go with the separate Azure Active Directory along with separate subscriptions so that you can track the billing details for each organization.

We cannot track the billing details with single subscriptions for each organization separately. You can have one billing for 2 subscriptions and you cannot have more than billing for 2 subscriptions. Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/view-all-accounts#microsoft-online-services-program) to get more information and see if it helps. If you have any further queries kindly let me know